# Java - JPA Repeatable @Embedded annotations

Tags: java, jpa

All tables in our shop have the same set of identical audit columns(system, user, terminal, etc)
So instead of copying the same columns in every class I tried to use the embedded annotation

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class ProdEntity implements Serializable{
private long prod;
//set/get code

private CommonJrnFields jrn;
@Embedded
    public CommonJrnFields getJrn() {return this.jrn;}
    public void setJrn(CommonJrnFields jrn) {this.jrn = jrn;}

private OrdEntity ord;
@OneToOne(mappedBy="prod")
    public OrdEntity getOrd() {return this.ord;}
    public void setOrd(OrdEntity ord) {this.ord = ord;}
}

@Entity
@Table(name="ORDERS")
@NamedQuery(name="OrdEntity.findAll", query="SELECT o FROM OrdEntity o")
public class OrdEntity extends ProdEntity implements Serializable{
private long ord;
//set/get code

private CommonJrnFields jrn;
@Embedded
    public CommonJrnFields getJrn() {return this.jrn;}
    public void setJrn(CommonJrnFields jrn) {this.jrn = jrn;}

private ProdEntity prod;
@OneToOne(mappedBy="ord")
    public ProdEntity getProd () {return this.prod;}
    public void setProd(ProdEntity prod) {this.prod = prod;}
}

@Embeddable 
public class CommonJrnFields  {
private String user;
private String system;
//set/get code
}
```

As a result embedded columns of extended class overrides base class and named query returns

```
ProdEntity.prod
OrdEntity.ord
OrdEntity.system
OrdEntity.user
```

instead of

```
ProdEntity.prod
ProdEntity.system
ProdEntity.user
OrdEntity.ord
OrdEntity.system
OrdEntity.user
```

How to fix it?

Please do not offer the @AttributeOverrides solution.
I'm working with almost 100 tables and do attribute override in each class for 8 common columns specifying table="" does not make any sense. It would be much faster just to cut/paste the embeddable code into all entities if there is no other solutions.

Comment: The superclass already has `jrn`, why did you feel you needed to repeat it in the subclass?

Comment: This is how database designed -- each table has the same set of audit columns. I need to pull all columns from all tables. Users can add a new product today and place an order tomorrow. The requirement is to pull all audit info. Also, in my example insert fails with exception "The number of actual and formal parameters differs, or an unwrapping conversion has failed"

Comment: I still fail to understand. Why does `OrdEntity` inherit from `ProdEntity` *and at the same time* contain `ProdEntity` as a field? Is this intentional? Also, as I mentioned, you already have `jrn` in `OrdEntity` - it's inherited from the superclass. Do you want two `user` and two `system` columns in the same table?

Comment: Furthermore, the default JPA inheritance strategy is `SINGLE_TABLE`, so if the use of inheritance is intentional, `@Table(name="ORDERS")` doesn't make sense. It would be easier if you described your domain model, or - even better - the desired DB structure for `PRODUCT` and `ORDERS`

Comment: Again, EACH table in database has the same set of jrn columns. The goal is to pull these columns from all involved tables as shown in example. OrdEntity has ProdEntity as a field for ability to pull parent record. The above is just a simplified example of the real database tables. In reality each table has a number of columns and it was designed as OneToOne relation. Yes, it is bad design, logical solution would be just to add extra columns to PROD, but it is too late to redesign.  OrdEntity contains some extra fields. The real orders are OrdDtlEntity  and it is ManyToOne to PROD and ORDER